# Вызов событий Angular 4

Tags: angular2, angular4

Ребят, кто знает как реализовать следующие в Angular 4:

Допустим у нас есть кнопки

```
<button id="btn-1">Click1</button>
<button id="btn-2">Click2</button>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопке с id="btn-2" генерировался(вызывался) клик на кнопке c id="btn-1"?
Какой код должен быть в компонентах этих кнопок?

В jquey это бы выглядело бы так:

```
$('#btn-2').click(function() {
    $('#btn-1').click();
});
```

Как это реализовать в Angular 4?

Answer (score 2):

id тут без надобности

```
<button (click)="btn2.click()">Click1</button>
<button #btn2>Click2</button>
```